# Racket: Iterating through two lists with different size

Tags: scheme, racket

I have two lists namely

`(a b c d)`

which is a set (list of unique elments) and

`((a 2) (a 1) (b 3) (c 1) (c 4) (c 2) (c 5) (d 3)`

Now, I want a list containing all the elements in the first list grouped together something like this.

`((a 2 1 3) (b 3) (c 1 4 2 5) (d 3))`

I achieved the above using two for loops `(for ((ele1 lst1)) ...)` and `(for ((ele2 lst2)) ...)` but not satisfied with my solution. I have also seen `group-by` primitve but that is not exactly what I am looking for.

I think, there is a better and elegant functional solution. Am I right? Can any Racketer tell me that?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using `Racket`.
Here is my iterative code for achieving the same.

```
(define (student-log log)
   (for ((n unique-names))
      (let ((l (list n)))
         (for ((i data))
            (cond ((equal? n (car i))
               (set! l (append l (list (cadddr i)))))))
      (set! log (append log (list l))))) log)
```

I am using a local variable `l` and using `set!` to reset the value of both `l` and `log`.  It looks more like **procedural** than **functional**.

Comment: Which of the languages that you tagged this question with are you actually using?

Comment: Why is there a `3` in the `a` segment?

Comment: Please post your solution, and explain what makes it inelegant.

Comment: I am using Racket.  Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @Sorawee Porncharoenwase

```
(define (group-by-my-rule mix-ls)
  (map (λ (ls) (cons (first (first ls)) (map second ls)))
         (group-by first mix-ls)))

(group-by-my-rule '((a 1) (a 2) (a 3) (b 1) (e 2) (c 2) (c 3) (c 4) (d 1) (e 1) (c 1)))
```

Comment: Why is `index-sp` needed? You can simply use `first` and it would give the same result, and it's much more efficient asymptotically.

Comment: @tjorchrt Hi, when I just copied and pasted your code, I am getting the error `ls is undefined`.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase and @tjorchrt, thanks.  I was wondering why to use the first list at all.  I can achieve by using the second list only.  Still, I am not clear with second `map` call. Also, I am getting an error when I copy/paste the second solution.  (refer my previous comment).